# How to Make Enter Key Behave Like Tab for Focus Change in Material-UI Dialog Inputs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-components

I'm working on a React project using Material-UI, and I've run into a challenge with input focus management within a dialog. My dialog consists of several input fields, and I want to alter the default behavior so that pressing the Enter key moves the focus to the next input field, much like how the Tab key works.

```
                 ***version of material-ui : "@mui/material": "^5.13.5".*
```

```
// Component that renders my form dialog which is the one with the issue
// <AddInvoiceDialog> is not rendered directly because eventually will be other dialogs

import React from "react";
import { InteractionContext } from "../../hooks/ContextProvider";
import { useContext } from "react";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import { useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";

import React from "react";
import { InteractionContext } from "../../hooks/ContextProvider";
import { useContext } from "react";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import { useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";
import TableDialogComponent from "./TableDialogComponent";
import DialogsId from "../../helper/DialogsHelper";
import AlertDialog from "./AlertDialog";
import ConfirmDeleteDialog from "./ConfirmDeleteDialog";
import AddInvoiceDialog from "./AddInvoiceDialog";
import EditInvoiceDialog from "./EditInvoiceDialog";
import AddReceptionDialog from "./AddReceptionDialog";
import EditReceptionDialog from "./EditReceptionDialog";
import AddExpenseRecordDialog from "./AddExpenseRecord";
import EditExpenseRecordDialog from "./EditExpenseRecordDialog";
import DuplicateExpenseRecordDialog from "./DuplicateExpenseRecordDialog";

function switchDialogId(dialogId) {
  switch (dialogId) {
    case DialogsId.ADD_INVOICEDIALOG:
      return <AddInvoiceDialog />;
    // other cases 
    default:
      return <NotFoundDialog />;
  }
}

function MainDialog({ open }) {
  const { setShowDialog, dialogTitle, dialogId } =
    useContext(InteractionContext);
  const handleCloseDialog = () => {
    setShowDialog(false);
  };

  const matches = useMediaQuery("(min-width:600px)");

  const getDialogWidth = () => {
    switch (dialogId) {
        //cases...
        return "sm";
    }
  };
  return (
    <Dialog
      onClose={handleCloseDialog}
      open={open}
      maxWidth={getDialogWidth()}
      sx={{ overflow: "hidden" }}
      title={dialogTitle}
    >
      {switchDialogId(dialogId)}
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default MainDialog;
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  TextField,
  Autocomplete,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogActions,
  Grid,
  Divider,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Paper,
} from "@mui/material";
import DoneIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Done";
import CancelSharpIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CancelSharp";
import { SkeletonDictionary } from "../../helper/TablesHelper";
import { InteractionContext } from "../../hooks/ContextProvider";
import SpinnerComponent from "../stateless/SpinnerComponent";
import { DialogActionsDict } from "../../helper/DialogsHelper";
import { addSingleRecord, getAllTableData } from "../../utils/GlobalFunctions";
import { ProductSkeleton } from "../../skeletons/ProductSkeleton";
import { CustomerSkeleton } from "../../skeletons/CustomerSkeleton";
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import DialogsId from "../../helper/DialogsHelper";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

function AddInvoiceDialog() {
  const [selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts] = useState([]);
  const [avaliableProducts, setAvailableProducts] = useState([]);
  const [avaliableCustomers, setAvailableCustomers] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCustomer, setSelectedCustomer] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [productQuantities, setProductQuantities] = useState({});
  const [finalPrice, setFinalPrice] = useState({});
  const [date, setDate] = useState(dayjs());

  const {
    tableId,
    setShowDialog,
    setDialogId,
    dialogData,
    setDialogData,
    dialogTitle,
    setIndexTableReload,
  } = React.useContext(InteractionContext);

  const handleProductChange = (event, newValues) => {
    setSelectedProducts(newValues);
    const newQuantities = newValues.reduce(
      (acc, product) => ({
        ...acc,
        [product.pCod]: productQuantities[product.pCod] || 1,
      }),
      {}
    );
    const newFinalPrice = newValues.reduce(
      (acc, product) => ({
        ...acc,
        [product.pCod]: finalPrice[product.pCod] || product.priceSale,
      }),
      {}
    );
    setFinalPrice(newFinalPrice);
    setProductQuantities(newQuantities);
  };

  const handleCustomerChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setSelectedCustomer(newValue);
  };

  const handleQuantityChange = (productId, event) => {
    setProductQuantities({
      ...productQuantities,
      [productId]: Number(event.target.value),
    });
  };

  const handleFinalPriceChange = (productId, event) => {
    setFinalPrice({
      ...finalPrice,
      [productId]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const adjustProductsToSendRequest = () => {
    //[@check_legacy]
    const productsToSend = selectedProducts.map((product) => ({
      ...product,
      // In the line below we send the remaining stock of the product
      inStock:
        Number(avaliableProducts.find((i) => i.pCod === product.pCod).inStock) -
        Number(productQuantities[product.pCod]),
      // In the line below we send the final sale price of the product...
      priceSale: Number(finalPrice[product.pCod]),
      quantitySale: Number(productQuantities[product.pCod]),
    }));
    return productsToSend;
  };

  const buildInvoiceRequest = () => {
    //[@check_legacy]
    const calculateTotalItems = () => {
      let totalItems = 0;
      selectedProducts.forEach((product) => {
        const quantity = Number(productQuantities[product.pCod]) || 1;
        totalItems += quantity;
      });
      return Number(totalItems);
    };
    const calculateDiscount = () => {
      let totalDiscount = 0;
      selectedProducts.forEach((product) => {
        const quantity = productQuantities[product.pCod] || 1;
        const price = finalPrice[product.pCod] || product.priceSale;
        totalDiscount += quantity * (product.priceSale - price);
      });
      return totalDiscount;
    };

    dialogData.customerId = selectedCustomer.cCod;
    dialogData.date = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    dialogData.amount = totalAmount;
    dialogData.itemQty = calculateTotalItems();
    dialogData.status = 2;
    dialogData.rdate = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    dialogData.discount = calculateDiscount();

    const bodyrequest = {
      invoice: dialogData,
      products: adjustProductsToSendRequest(),
    };
    return bodyrequest;
  };

  const handleSuccessPost = (response) => {
    //[@check_legacy]
    setShowDialog(false);
    setDialogId(DialogsId.ALERTDIALOG);
    setDialogData({
      message: `Successfully invoice added!`,
      color: "success",
      icon: <DoneIcon />,
      actions: [{ text: "Ok", color: "success", callback: null }],
      title: "Success",
    });
    setShowDialog(true);
  };

  const handleErrorPost = (error) => {
    //[@check_legacy]
    setDialogId(DialogsId.ALERTDIALOG);
    setDialogData({
      message: `Something went wrong!`,
      color: "error",
      icon: <CancelSharpIcon />,
      actions: [{ text: "Ok", color: "error", callback: null }],
      title: "Error",
    });
  };

  const handlePost = async () => {
    //[@check_legacy]
    const bodyRequest = buildInvoiceRequest();
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await addSingleRecord(bodyRequest, tableId);
    if (response.statusCode === 201) {
      // status created
      handleSuccessPost(response);
    } else {
      handleErrorPost(response);
    }
    setLoading(false);
    setIndexTableReload((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    // fetch products and customers
    const productsUrl = ProductSkeleton.endpoints.getAll;
    const customersUrl = CustomerSkeleton.endpoints.getAll;
    Promise.all([getAllTableData(productsUrl), getAllTableData(customersUrl)])
      .then(([products, customers]) => {
        setAvailableProducts(products);
        setAvailableCustomers(customers);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        //TODO -> handle error, a global error variable should be valuated
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  // Calculate total amount
  const totalAmount = selectedProducts.reduce((total, product) => {
    const quantity = productQuantities[product.pCod] || 1;
    return total + quantity * finalPrice[product.pCod];
  }, 0);

  const labelForButton = (save) => (save ? "Add Invoice" : "Dismiss");

  if (loading) {
    return <SpinnerComponent></SpinnerComponent>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <DialogTitle
        id={`${SkeletonDictionary[tableId].identifier}-dialog`}
        textAlign={"start"}
      >
        {dialogTitle}
      </DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={2}
        >
          <Grid
            item
            xs={8}
          >
            <Autocomplete
              className="my-2"
              options={avaliableCustomers}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
              onChange={handleCustomerChange}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label="Select a customer"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
              )}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            xs={4}
          >
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
              <DatePicker
                className=" w-100 my-2"
                label="Date"
                value={date}
                onChange={(newDate) => setDate(newDate ? dayjs(newDate) : null)}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            xs={12}
          >
            <Divider
              variant="middle"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 26)" }}
              className="mx-0"
            />
            <Typography
              color="text.info"
              variant="body2"
              className="mt-2"
            >
              Add Products
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            xs={8}
          >
            <Autocomplete
              className="my-2"
              multiple
              options={avaliableProducts}
              value={selectedProducts}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
              onChange={handleProductChange}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label="Select products by name"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
              )}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            xs={4}
          >
            <Autocomplete
              className="my-2"
              multiple
              options={avaliableProducts}
              value={selectedProducts}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => String(option.pCod)}
              onChange={handleProductChange}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label="Select products by code"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
              )}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            xs={12}
          >
            <Typography
              color="text.info"
              variant="body2"
              className="mb-2"
            >
              Products
            </Typography>
            <Divider
              variant="middle"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 26)" }}
              className="mx-0"
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            xs={12}
          >
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
              <Table>
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>Product</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Quantity</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Stock</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Price</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Amount</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {selectedProducts.map((product) => {
                    const quantity = productQuantities[product.pCod] || 1;
                    const price = finalPrice[product.pCod] || product.priceSale;
                    const amount = quantity * price;
                    return (
                      <TableRow key={product.pCod}>
                        <TableCell
                          component="th"
                          scope="row"
                        >
                          {product.name}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                          <TextField
                            type="number"
                            size="small"
                            value={quantity}
                            onChange={(event) =>
                              handleQuantityChange(product.pCod, event)
                            }
                            inputProps={{ min: 1 }}
                            sx={{ width: "5vw" }}
                          />
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{product.inStock}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                          <TextField
                            type="number"
                            size="small"
                            value={price}
                            onChange={(event) =>
                              handleFinalPriceChange(product.pCod, event)
                            }
                            sx={{ width: "7vw" }}
                            InputProps={{
                              startAdornment: (
                                <InputAdornment position="start">
                                  $
                                </InputAdornment>
                              ),
                            }}
                            inputProps={{ min: 0.01 }}
                          ></TextField>
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell>
                          ${amount.toFixed(2)} {/* assuming price is a float */}
                        </TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    );
                  })}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            xs={3}
          >
            <TextField
              label="Total Amount"
              value={`$${totalAmount.toFixed(2)}`}
              size="small"
              InputProps={{
                readOnly: true,
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            xs={9}
          >
            <DialogActions>
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-success"
                onClick={(event) => {
                  handlePost();
                }}
              >
                {`${labelForButton(true)}`}
              </button>
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-dark mx-2"
                onClick={(e) => setShowDialog(false)}
              >
                {`${labelForButton(false)}`}
              </button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </DialogContent>
    </>
  );
}

export default AddInvoiceDialog;
```

I suspect the issue might be related to how Material-UI handles focus within dialogs, but I'm not sure how to address this. Does anyone have suggestions or solutions for making the Enter key behave like the Tab key in this context? . Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

- I've set up a ref array to manage references to the input fields.
- I've implemented a custom keypress handler to shift focus to the next input when the Enter key is pressed.

Despite these efforts, pressing Enter doesn't change the focus as expected. Every time that I press the enter key from one of my inputs components I can see the message 'Enter key pressed' from the console and there are not errors but the focus never happens.

Comment: I put a dummy together in codesandbox and it worked: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-faraday-rjshqn?file=/src/App.js. Possible browser difference? What you using? The approach you have taken is roughly sound.

Comment: It could also be some other listener on your application, like a global one, coming from some other script. Do you have any third party `<script>` tags or anything along those lines?

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. Indeed, the dialog in my application is a bit more complex than the example. I will update the post with the original AddInvoiceDialog code for clarity. Your input has been very helpful, as it provided a new perspective. I had been fixated on the issue being related to the library itself.

Regarding browsers, I have tested the application on Edge, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: Well, I have forgotten completely about but I have Bootstrap added also I will check.

Comment: Sir, you are completely right about it, it was the m...er bootstrap.js listener, my goodness, how much did it take you to figure it out... like 300 seconds...? LOL, you should hire me... I'll work for free for you LOL. Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the bootstrap.js listener... removing it fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).